# How to create new text search dictionary

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search

I want to create a new text search dictionary for PostgreSQL that will perform the recognition of synonyms. The dictionary should use .syn file. I created file in TextEdit with synonyms and saved .syn file on desktop. After that I tried to run next block of code in pgAdmin4

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY xy
( TEMPLATE = synonym,
SYNONYMS = 'xy.syn');
```

But I get ERROR:  invalid text search configuration file name "xy.syn"
SQL state: 22023

I can't find out what am I doing wrong? Do I have to save .syn file somewhere else or is there any way to create some kind of file with synonyms inside pgAdmin4? I am using macbook air m1

Comment: The docs tell you how to name and where to install the file.  Did you try doing that?  (Probably not by using pgamdin4)

Answer (score 1):

If the synonym file is called `xy.syn`, you should use `SYNONYMS = 'xy'` in your definition.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with saving .syn file from vscode.