# PostgreSQL .syn file : invalid text search configuration file name

Tags: postgresql

I have a project where I have to create a .syn file to create a local dictionary that changes a world in his synonym. I'm using pgAdmin4 (version 16)

It is impossible for me to access the `.syn` I've created.

I've tried some possibilities already, changing my .syn folder emplacement (C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/share/tsearch_data/am56314Syn.syn as an example).

Also changing security authorization on the folder and file.

Here's some of the SQL query:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY am56314syn 
(
    TEMPLATE = pg_catalog.synonym,
    SYNONYMS = 'C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\16\\data\\am56314Syn.syn'
);

CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY am56314syn 
(
    TEMPLATE = pg_catalog.synonym,
    SYNONYMS = 'tsearch_data/am56314Syn.syn'
);
```

I always get the same error :

> ERROR:  invalid text search configuration file name "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/share/tsearch_data/am56314Syn.syn"
>
> SQL state: 22023

`22023` is for ERRCODE_INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE

I've also tried to use the 'simple' mode

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY am56314syn (
    TEMPLATE = 'simple'
);
```

and then (this code is working)

```
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION am56314
ALTER MAPPING FOR word, asciiword
WITH am56314syn, simple;
```

Here is one of the solution already posted [How to create new text search dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74116812/how-to-create-new-text-search-dictionary) but I have no clue on how to do it.

Comment: If I am following this [Text Search Dictionaries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-SYNONYM-DICTIONARY) correctly this `'tsearch_data/am56314Syn.syn'` should be `tam56314Syn.syn`.